# Not able to add all Landsat8 data folders to Mosaic dataset in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, landsat-8, mosaic-dataset

I have a set of folders from Landsat data, each folder is of a different year. When I add all these folders to add rasters to the mosaic dataset tool. The final output shows me data for only one year that is beginning. The rest of the years don't show up. I have downloaded the Landsat collection 2 level 2 data for this work. I have also tried with level 1 data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the 2022 landsat data belongs to landsat 9.So while adding 2022 data to mosaic, we are supposed to change the sensor/product type in drop down from landsat 8 to landsat 9.